# While Loops with Two IF Statements

Tags: c, loops

I have a script that reads in a file using a while loop.  One IF statement reads the line (it is a csv file) then a second checks for a match.

```
while ( file != NULL )
{
    if ( sscanf to read the line )
    {
        if ( to check for matches)
        {
            toggle variable
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I add the break into the second IF statement (as above) will that break out of the **two IF** statements and the **WHILE** loop?  Or do I need additional `break;` to get out of thw while loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to know the behaviour of break statement in C. Does it work only for ';for-while-do-switch' or also for 'if-statements'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565659/i-want-to-know-the-behaviour-of-break-statement-in-c-does-it-work-only-for-fo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `break` or `continue` statement is for the nearest *loop*. The `if` statements are not even considered.

The exception of course being `break` within a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Any `break` within a `while` loop will break out of that loop. `break` ignores `if` statements.