# How to stop(break) "for" loop in c#?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I need to stop "for" cycle before it ends by itself. I have one "for" cycle in other. Here is my code(a simple example):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    //stop "for" cycle
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to stop the "for" cycle which is inside without stopping outside one.
Which command should I use to manage that?

Comment: `break`.. Is it so hard to try?

Comment: use break as you suggested

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to know the behaviour of break statement in C. Does it work only for ';for-while-do-switch' or also for 'if-statements'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565659/i-want-to-know-the-behaviour-of-break-statement-in-c-does-it-work-only-for-fo)

Comment: Next time before you ask a question, try googling the exact title you're about to ask, and see if you get any results that might help.

Comment: I don't think this question is worth -4: it has *nested* loops and so the answer is not obvious. Plus it's well-posed with a short example.

Comment: From the early comments, I am guessing OP originally suggested using `break` himself, and then edited it out inside the edit-window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just one layer of loop, you can use `break`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            break; // <== Exits the 'j' loop, returns control
                   //     to the 'i' loop which continues
        }
    }
}
```

For nested loops, you may want to use a variable (for instance, a `bool`) that you set to a break condition. Looking at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx), I don't think C# has directed breaks as some other languages do.

```
bool keepGoing = true;
for (int i = 0; keepGoing && i < 100; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; keepGoing && j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            keepGoing = false; // Stops both
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i == 5)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` statements (which exit the innermost loop), or even a *break to a label*. Personally I don't like the latter as it means you need to maintain that label which makes code hard to read.

If you need to exit right out of an elaborate nested `for` loop structure then encode the whole thing in a function and use `return`. You can then even return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to break two loops with a single command? Use a goto.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        if (i == 10 && j == 50)
            goto Exit;
    }

    continue;

Exit:
    break;
}
```

Other has already posted how to break just the inner loop.